# Mtools not found on Minix 3.2.1

Tags: minix

I can't use the mtools command on Minix 3.2.1, i tried installing all the packages whit pkgin-all but didnt work, still saying mtools: not found when trying to use it
How can I install it?

Answer (score 0):

In MINIX 3.2.1 Mtools are not supported anymore. I don't know why they did that. I believe you are using Mtools for file transfer between MINIX to other operating systems. Well there is very easy method now. You have to use openssh ( networking thing ) for that. Just install openssh and login your MINIX 3 system with a ssh client. Here is an article " [Install openssh on minix 3](http://siddharthshankermishra.wordpress.com/2014/09/04/file-transfer-between-minix-3-windows-in-virtualbox/)"